# Returning Separate Lists of Items from a Multidimensional Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have the following array:

```
$items = array(
'item_1' => array('sub-item_1_A','sub-item_1_B', 'sub-item_1_C', 'sub-item_1_D', 'sub-item_1_E'),
'item_2' => array('sub-item_2_A','sub-item_2_B', 'sub-item_2_C'),
'item_3' => array('sub-item_3_A','sub-item_3_B', 'sub-item_3_C', , 'sub-item_3_D'),
'item_4' => array('sub-item_4_A','sub-item_4_B'),
'item_5' );
```

The first thing I want to do is return a list of just the items -- i.e., the following:

```
item_1, item_2, item_3, item_4, item_5
```

I need that list in and of itself.

I ALSO need to then use that list to create SEPARATE lists of each of the the sub-arrays.  I.e., here is one list:

```
'sub-item_1_A','sub-item_1_B', 'sub-item_1_C', 'sub-item_1_D', 'sub-item_1_E'
```

And here is the next list:

```
'sub-item_2_A','sub-item_2_B', 'sub-item_2_C'
```

And so on.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**
I do not want to return the sub-items as a string, but rather I just wish to be able to access the sub-items of each item individually.

Comment: I see you need a couple of things done. What have you tried so far? Any attempts?

Comment: I tried something like the following (I didn't save my attempts):  

foreach ( $items as $item ) { echo 'Item: ' . $item[0]; }

I believe that just returns 'item5' each and every time.  I tried without the [0] and it also did not work (I think I got an error, if memory serves).  Note -- this was an attempt simply to get  a list of the first order items [my first need].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$items = array(
            'item_1' => array('sub-item_1_A','sub-item_1_B', 'sub-item_1_C', 'sub-item_1_D', 'sub-item_1_E'),
            'item_2' => array('sub-item_2_A','sub-item_2_B', 'sub-item_2_C'),
            'item_3' => array('sub-item_3_A','sub-item_3_B', 'sub-item_3_C',  'sub-item_3_D'),
            'item_4' => array('sub-item_4_A','sub-item_4_B'),
            'item_5' => '');

foreach($items as $key => $item)
{
    echo '<h3>'.$key.'</h3>';
    if(!empty($item))
    {
        foreach($item as $k => $v)
        {
            echo '<h5>'.$v.'</h5>';
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you

```
item_1
sub-item_1_A
sub-item_1_B
sub-item_1_C
sub-item_1_D
sub-item_1_E
item_2
sub-item_2_A
sub-item_2_B
sub-item_2_C
item_3
sub-item_3_A
sub-item_3_B
sub-item_3_C
sub-item_3_D
item_4
sub-item_4_A
sub-item_4_B
item_5
```

Comment: This is exact what I need.  Thanks.

Comment: Great ;) glad to help you ;)

Answer (score 2):

[Online Check](https://3v4l.org/d0aY3), A working example.

To make the "return a list of just the items" you need to use just `array_keys`.

```
$list_of_first = array_keys($items);
```

**return a list of just the items:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => item_1
    [1] => item_2
    [2] => item_3
    [3] => item_4
    [4] => item_5
)
```

You can change it to a list by using implode here.

And for the rest you need a `foreach loop` and use the implode to get the array items as string like yo want.

```
foreach($items as $val){
    echo implode(", ", $val)."<br/>";
}
```

**List of sub array's:**

```
sub-item_1_A, sub-item_1_B, sub-item_1_C, sub-item_1_D, sub-item_1_E
sub-item_2_A, sub-item_2_B, sub-item_2_C
sub-item_3_A, sub-item_3_B, sub-item_3_C, sub-item_3_D
sub-item_4_A, sub-item_4_B
sub-item_5_A, sub-item_5_B
```

Comment: Thanks.  array_keys is what I was looking for.  In terms of the second part -- I actually don't want the values returned as a string.  I want to access each list separately (and programmatically).  As such, is it possible to modify your answer to show me how to use `foreach` to simply return each sub-array by individually?

Comment: Yes, why not?? What you want to know?

Comment: @Moshe, you can look for the `$val` which is the sub array, and this is return from the foreach.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help:

first you need to get the all array keys and implode it to get the items list. To get sub items list you need to loop through the array values.

```
<?php

$items = array(
'item_1' => array('sub-item_1_A','sub-item_1_B', 'sub-item_1_C', 'sub-item_1_D', 'sub-item_1_E'),
'item_2' => array('sub-item_2_A','sub-item_2_B', 'sub-item_2_C'),
'item_3' => array('sub-item_3_A','sub-item_3_B', 'sub-item_3_C', 'sub-item_3_D'),
'item_4' => array('sub-item_4_A','sub-item_4_B'),
'item_5' => "");

echo $itemsList = implode(',',array_keys($items))."\n";
$subItemsList = array_values($items);
foreach ($subItemsList as $key=>$value) {
    if (!empty($value))
        echo $subItemsList = implode(',',$value)."\n";

}
```